# Removing Grey and White Chequered background in Android Image Asset Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image

I am trying to remove the Grey and White Chequered background from a launcher icon jpg file using Android Studio's Image Asset.But no luck so far. 
Is there any way to do this?

below is the Background :

[image]

Comment: You can set your own background or you can leave a transparent background. Use this link to generate your launcher icon https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher

Answer (score 1):

The checkerboard background is for transparency. Same happens in paint.net. If you end up with transparency, you get a checkerboard like that of white and grey.

It is technically not a background, you don't actually see that in the launcher. Alpha shows as a checkerboard to ensure you know you are seeing alpha. If you install it on a device, you can see what is "under" the launcher icon. If your icon is 256x256, and has a 10x10 square of transparency in the middle, you will see a checkerboard there too. If you then launch it on the device and check the launcher, you will see that there is a see-through hole in the middle.

Basically, the checkerboard isn't a background - it is transparency.

With the exception of the times where you actually create a checkerboard on purpose, but that can then be deleted by modifying the .png file

Comment: how can i prevent from getting displayed? Currently I have changed the background using the paint.net

Comment: It only shows for alpha, and it doesn't render in the final product. It doesn't really matter if it is there in ANdroid Studio (or in Paint.net for that matter). If you open it in some picture viewing software (not editing) there is no checkerboard, it looks like the background. I don't think you can hide the alpha rendering in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on image, form the menu that pops up select Hide Chessboard.[image: hide chessboard]